# How to show QMenu on left click

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit, qmenu

The `QMenu` shows up on a `QLineEdit` right-click.
**Question**: How to modify this code to show the menu on a left-click as well?

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

    def actionFunct(self, argBool):
        print 'actionFunct()', argBool

    def buildGUI(self):
        self.line=QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.setText('My Line Edit')      

        self.menu=QMenu(self.line)

        self.line.installEventFilter(self)
        self.menu.installEventFilter(self)

        for i in range(3):
            actn=QAction('Action 0%s'%i, self.menu, checkable=True)
            actn.triggered.connect(self.actionFunct)
            self.menu.addAction(actn)

        self.line.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.line.connect(self.line, SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.lineClicked)

        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def lineClicked(self, QPos):
        print 'lineClicked', QPos
        parentPosition = self.line.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))        
        menuPosition = parentPosition + QPos

        self.menu.move(menuPosition)
        self.menu.show() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.buildGUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an eventFilter method on your Window class to filter/handle the event.

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj == self.line and isinstance(event, QMouseEvent) and event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
        self.lineClicked(event.pos())
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 5):

## SOLUTION # 1 (Thanks to Brendan Abel).

Use `installEventFilter()` method to route all the lineedit events via easy-to-be-customized `eventFilter()` method:

```
self.line.installEventFilter(self)
```

Now all the events `self.line` triggers are going to go through `eventFilter`. There using received `event` object we query postion using:

```
event.pos()
```

which we send to `leftClicked()` methods as an argument (the same method is called on lineeidit's right-click).
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    import sys

```
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

    def actionFunct(self, argBool):
        print 'actionFunct()', argBool

    def buildGUI(self):
        self.line=QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.setText('My Line Edit')      
        self.line.installEventFilter(self)

        self.menu=QMenu(self.line)

        for i in range(3):
            actn=QAction('Action 0%s'%i, self.menu, checkable=True)
            actn.triggered.connect(self.actionFunct)
            self.menu.addAction(actn)

        self.line.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.line.connect(self.line, SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.leftClicked)

        self.line.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.leftClicked)

        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        print 'eventFilter', widget, event
        if widget == self.line and isinstance(event, QMouseEvent) and event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.leftClicked(event.pos())
            return True
        return False

    def leftClicked(self, QPos):
        print 'leftClicked', QPos
        parentPosition = self.line.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))        
        menuPosition = parentPosition + QPos

        self.menu.move(menuPosition)
        self.menu.show() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.buildGUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## SOLUTION # 2

First connect `QLineEdit`'s easiest-to-trigger `cursorPositionChanged` signal to a method. 
When on a left-click this method is called query the current mouse cursor position with Qt's `QCursor.pos()`:

```
current_mouse_cursor=QCursor.pos()
```

which returns something like:

```
QtCore.QPoint(852, 595)
```

Finally move the menu to a queried mouse cursor position and show it:

```
    self.menu.move(current_mouse_cursor)
    self.menu.show()
```

[image]

A working code is posted below:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

    def actionFunct(self, argBool):
        print 'actionFunct()', argBool

    def buildGUI(self):
        self.line=QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.setText('My Line Edit')      

        self.menu=QMenu(self.line)

        for i in range(3):

            actn=QAction('Action 0%s'%i, self.menu, checkable=True)
            actn.triggered.connect(self.actionFunct)
            self.menu.addAction(actn)

        self.line.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.line.connect(self.line, SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.rightClicked)

        self.line.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.leftClicked)

        layout=QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def leftClicked(self, arg):
        print 'leftClicked', arg, QCursor.pos()
        self.menu.move(QCursor.pos())
        self.menu.show() 

    def rightClicked(self, QPos):
        print 'rightClicked', QPos
        parentPosition = self.line.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))        
        menuPosition = parentPosition + QPos

        self.menu.move(menuPosition)
        self.menu.show() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.buildGUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `cursorPositionChanged` is triggered for other events besides just left mouse clicking.  It's triggered when typing in the lineedit as well and when moving the cursor using the arrow keys.